# I pass data from database in array form, then I want to show this array in php

Tags: php, arrays, database

How do I use `$objects` in this function?
I pass data from database in array form, then I want to show this array in PHP page, but it's printing this word "array".

I want to print it in this format--> [ ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'], ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'], ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'] ]
The code:

```
    function showing_daily_basket(){

    $connect_mysql= @mysql_connect($server,$username,$passwor) or die ("Connection Failed!");
    $mysql_db=mysql_select_db("GP15",$connect_mysql) or die ("Could not Connect to Database");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM basket_daily_work";
    $result=mysql_query($query) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
            $objects= array();
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
                    $objects[]= $rows;
    }
    exit($objects);
 }
```

> and if i paste this var_dump($objects);' after while loop this the result 
>   Blockquote

[image: the result]

AFTER edit it's return nothing

```js
$connect_mysql= @mysql_connect($server,$username,$passwor) or die ("Connection Failed!");
$mysql_db=mysql_select_db("GP15",$connect_mysql) or die ("Could not Connect to Database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM basket_daily_work";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
            $objects= array();
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
                    $objects[]= $rows;
    }
 var_dump($objects);
$data_set = "[";
$count_rows = count($objects);
$count = 1;
foreach($objects as $object){
    $data_set .= "['". $object['basketID'] ."', '". $object['date'] ."', '". $object['time'] ."', '". $object['flag'] ."']";
    if($count != $count_rows){
        $data_set .= ",";
        $count++;
    }
}
$data_set .= "]";
echo $data_set;
```

Comment: If you just want to print it in default format, use print_r($objects); before exit.

Comment: I want to print it in this format-->
[   ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'] ]

Comment: What do you see if you var_dump($data_set); ?

Comment: it's work finally I just didn't recognize the result :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be an array within `$objects` for each row that was returned in your query. So you can loop through these and then do something with the results.

```
foreach($objects as $object){
    echo $object['column_name'];
}
```

This code will echo out the value of the column name specified for each row returned.

A good way to see the structure of $objects before doing something with the results is

```
print "<pre>";
var_dump($objects);
```

EDIT - Try this

```
$data_set = "[";
    $count_rows = count($objects);
    $count = 1;

    foreach($objects as $object){
        $data_set .= "['". $object['basketID'] ."', '". $object['date'] ."', '". $object['time'] ."', '". $object['flag'] ."']";

        if($count != $count_rows){
            $data_set .= ",";
            $count++;
        }
    }

    $data_set .= "]";
```

Comment: I want to print it in this format--> 
[ ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'], ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'], ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'] ]

Comment: i want to print values in this form [['value11','value12','value13','value14'],['value21','value22','value23','value24']]

Comment: acually i'm trying to get this value in this way to pass it to (datatables),, i want to apply as it's here  http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html so i can show the data table

Comment: at for each is it $object  or $objects ?

Comment: thank you it works with me finally :)) Appreciate your effort ^_^

Comment: what if i want to show a picture in my table I tried <img src""> but it's not working with me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30827169/i-want-to-show-pictures-in-datatables-table-plug-in-for-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Please try print_r($objects).

"print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable" - Refer to [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)